# Append new row in google spreadsheet with existing rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

I am trying to append new row in googlespreadsheet for that i have usied below script

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
import pandas as pd

ws = gc.open("test_submit").worksheet("Oct-2019")       

d = {'Name': ['T', 'Z'], 'ID': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
existing = get_as_dataframe(ws)
existing = existing.dropna(how='all')
updated = existing.append(df)
set_with_dataframe(ws, updated)
```

but it creates the unnecessary column in the blank column header with name unnamed0, unnamed1 ....unnamed. Moreover, it, not append row in the proper format of the existing column name. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I could know that my answer was not suitable for your question. So I have to delete my answer, because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. I would like to study more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved my problem using below script

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
import pandas as pd

ws = gc.open("test_submit").worksheet("Oct-2019")  

d = {'Name': ['T', 'Z'], 'ID': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
existing = get_as_dataframe(ws)
existing = existing.dropna(how='all')
new_df= pd.DataFrame()
new_df = new_df.append(existing)
new_df = new_df.append(df)
set_with_dataframe(ws, new_df,row=1, col=1, include_index=False, include_column_header=True,
                       resize=False, allow_formulas=True)
```